# AngularJS - Injecting Factory into Directive's link function

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, factory

I have a simple code:

```
define(['app'], function(app)
{
    app.factory('factoryProvider', function(){
        return {
            name: 'my Name'
        }
    });

    app.directive('myDiv',['factoryProvider', function(factoryProvider) {
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: true,
            templateUrl: 'link/to/template.html',
            controller: function($scope) {
            },
            link: function(scope, routeParams, location) {
                console.log(factoryProvider.name);
            }
        };   
    }])
});
```

I want to be able to access `myFactory`within the `link` function, but I can't! I also tried `link: function(scope, routeParams, location, factoryProvider)` and that also didn't work. Why?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It should already be available inside the link function

```
app.factory('factoryProvider', function(){
    return {
        name: 'my Name'
    }
});

app.directive('myDiv',['factoryProvider', function(factoryProvider) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        template: '<p>{{name}}</p>',
        controller: function($scope) {
        },
        link: function(scope) {
            scope.name=factoryProvider.name;
        }
    };
}]);
```

Comment: Well, it is defined for me, but when I get parameters returned, it says undefined. But the exact same method returns the parameter when used inside the controller.

Comment: It says can't find method of undefined or that the method is undefined? If factoryProvider is defined, what is it?

Comment: No, the returned value is undefined. When I log the factory inside link, it only shows a constructor. When I log it inside the controller, it shows all methods as well.

Comment: Uh idk, maybe the "Provider" is messing you up, try renaming your facotry

Comment: Haha, no it didn't! I changed it to randomNameTest and it still didn't work :p

Comment: You add extra arguments in your link function

Comment: I removed the extra argument, now I get `function compile($compileNodes, transcludeFn, maxPriority, ignoreDirective,
                        previousCompileContext) {....`

Comment: idk I've used the exact code I posted into my app and it works like a charm.

Comment: Okay thanks, Ill break it down to basics to find out what is going on!